# Groovy XmlSlurper Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, groovy

I am trying to parse an XML file and running into this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog
```

I've seen the other posts on SO, but my XML document looks OK - no extra characters or white space before the XML declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage SYSTEM "http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd">
<coverage branch-rate="0.24074074074074073" branches-covered="39" branches-valid="162" complexity="0" line-rate="0.3485915492957746" lines-covered="198" lines-valid="568" timestamp="1396622452625" version="0.2.6">
```

Here is the relevant portion of the script (Groovy 1.8.9):

```
def coveragedata = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(coverageFile)
```

Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
def parser = new XmlSlurper() 
parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true)
def coverageData = parser.parse( coverageFile )
```

Or if `coverageFile` is a String containing the xml from the file, as above, with `parseText` instead of `parse`:

```
parser.parseText( coverageFile )
```

Comment: I think that this would normally work, but using this solution gives me connection timeout errors.  This has to run on an internal network that does not have access to the internet which is why I want to ignore the DOCTYPE.

Comment: @JimG Try `new XmlSlurper( false, false )` as the constructor

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine:

```
def coveragedata = new XmlSlurper(false,false,true).parseText(coverageFile)
println coveragedata.'@branch-rate'
```

Comment: That would work with Groovy 2.x, but not with 1.8.9.

Comment: Also, assuming `coverageFile` is a `File`, You need `parse` not `pareText`

Comment: Well, in my code `coverageFile` was a name for `String` variable actually, but thanks!